# When working with natural units, how do my other variables change?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, dimensional-analysis, absolute-units

I'm trying to plot energy splitting

[image]

as a function of $a$ (where $g=1$). When I set $\hbar=1$ such that $a=[t^{-1}]$, how does the value of this variable change to keep the equation consistent?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking

Comment: Say a=2. Since hbar=[Js] in SI units, when I set hbar=[1], does this impact the value of a? Is the unit of a=[1/s] in this context as hbar=[Js]?

Comment: Energy splitting of *what*? What is $a$ physically? And what is $g$?

Comment: It's for a tunnelling approximation, so the energy splitting of the ground state of a potential in this case. a and g are simply parameters that define the shape of the symmetric double-well I'm using. I've arbitrarily set g=1 and am varying a to see how splitting decreases with increased well separation

Comment: You need to explain the *non*-natural dimensions of $a$ and $g$ before asking how to understand this equation in natural units. Give the symmetric double-well potential that you are using.

Comment: Using natural units where constants are set to 1, means you basically don't keep track of the units of anything, and just treat the quantities as pure numbers.  The focus is on the functional relationship between the variables

Comment: Your equation requires the dimensions of $a$ to be $ML^2T$ and the dimensions of $g$ to be $M^{-2}L^{-4}T^{-4}$. Both of these seem strange.

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do with an equation like this is "de-dimensionalize" it, so that you are working with dimensionless parameters.

Define $\varepsilon \equiv E/(g^{1/6}\hbar^{4/3})$ as a dimensionless energy parameter, and $\alpha \equiv a/(g^{-1/3}\hbar^{1/3})$ as a dimensionless form of your parameter $a$. Then your equation de-dimensionalizes to

$$\varepsilon_+ - \varepsilon_- = 8\sqrt\frac{2}{\pi}\alpha^{5/2}e^{-\tfrac43\alpha^3}$$

This really has nothing to do with "[natural units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_units#Natural_units_(particle_and_atomic_physics))" in the sense of setting $\hbar = c = 1$. Instead the "natural" energy scale here is $g^{1/6}\hbar^{4/3}$ and the "natural" scale for the parameter $a$ is $g^{-1/3}\hbar^{1/3}$.

(The peculiar dimensions of $g$ and $a$, however, make me wonder whether your equation is correct.)